# Draggable window with pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, draggable, pyqt4, drag

just a simple question: I'm using pyqt4 to render a simple window. Here's the code, I post the whole thing so it easier to explain.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
import time
import math

class FenixGui(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
            super(FenixGui, self).__init__()

        # setting layout type
        hboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(hboxlayout)

        # hiding title bar
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # setting window size and position
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 862, 560)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)

                # creating background window label
        backgroundpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixbackground.png")
        self.background = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.background.setPixmap(backgroundpixmap)
        self.background.setGeometry(0, 0, 862, 560)


        # fenix logo
        logopixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixlogo.png")
        self.logo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(logopixmap)
        self.logo.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 150)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    exm = FenixGui()
    exm.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, you see that I put a background label in my window. I would like that the window could be dragged around the screen by dragging this label. I mean: you click on the label, you drag the label, and the whole window comes around the screen. Is this possible? I accept non-elegant ways as well, because as you can see I hid the title bar so it would be impossible to drag the window if I don't make it draggable via the background label.

Hope I explained my problem properly
Thank you very much!!

Matteo Monti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override [mousePressEvent()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) and [mouseMoveEvent()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) to get the location of the mouse cursor and move your widget to that location.  `mousePressEvent` will give you the offset from the cursor position to the top left corner of your widget, and then you can calculate what the new position of the top left corner should be.  You can add these methods to your `FenixGui` class.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.offset = event.pos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    x=event.globalX()
    y=event.globalY()
    x_w = self.offset.x()
    y_w = self.offset.y()
    self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)
```

Comment: Ok, sorry again: I added these lines of code to add the listeners:
self.connect(self.background,QtCore.SIGNAL("mousePressEvent()"), self.backgroundmousepressevent)
        self.connect(self.background,QtCore.SIGNAL("mouseMoveEvent()"), self.backgroundmousemoveevent)

But nothing happens, I don't even think the event functions are called. Did I do something wrong...?

Comment: I don't believe that QWidget uses those signals.  I think you have to use the event handler functions.  If there is something else you want to do when those events occur, you can just add that code into the `mousePressEvent` and 'mouseMoveEvent' functions.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't move the window using the window manager like most other apps do. Somehow you can tell Qt to pass unused click events to the window manager, but I'm not sure how.